# Simple distribution problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $F_X(x)= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}arctan(x)$
And I know $Y = aX+b$

Does that make $F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}arctan(\frac{y-b}{a})$

Pretty sure $F_Y(y) = F_X(g^{-1}(x)$ where we have $g(x)=aX+b$?

One further question that I can't copy and past in the comment of the current only answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $F_Y(y)=P(Y \le y)=P(aX+b \le y)=P(aX \le y-b)=P(X \le \frac{y-b}{a})=F_X(\frac{y-b}{a})$

Comment: I see how that is derived now, thank you! One further question, what is $f_Y(y)$ here? I believe it is received by $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{|a|}f_X(\frac{y-b}{a})$ and I worked out $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$ so I take it $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{|a|*\pi(1+(\frac{y-b}{a})^2)}$